# Invite users to groups rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, polymorphic-associations

I'm building a simple rails app that allows users to login and create private lists for themselves, so far so good. I would like the user to then have the option to invite people to a certain list where these new users would have edit access to the tasks.  This would be in the same vein as basecamp and trello in regards to adding users.

Where would I begin to start with this I have been wracking my brains and searching google and can't find any relevant tutorials of guidance.

Comment: what's wrong with linking table to create many-to-many relationship between users and lists?

Comment: Did you ever get this setup going? New to has_many :through and I can't seem to get to the bottom of this type of association... @SamMason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what about having

```
1) A users Table (model)
2) A lists table (model)
```

Model Associations

```
A user has many lists
A list belongs to a user
```

User table will have Foreign Key list_id (you will need to add this via a migration)

Thats just a start, I am assuming you know about resources ( the big 7 ) in rails? As you will be using this extensively

Comment: I do actually currently have both a users table/ model and also a lists model/table the lists one of which has a user_id foreign key. But I'm struggling to get my head around how I would allow multiple users to have permission on one list. As for the big 7, no I have never heard of it. Do you have links?

Comment: its basically CRUD, create, read (show), update, destroy, but you also have new, delete and edit

Comment: what would the association be then? I am unaware of an association that covers both bases, one or many?

Comment: I would ideally have it so that a user would own a list (the one that created it) but that list could also have several other users associated with it, with less rights. I'm stuck on how to add these other associated users to the list table. I was hoping it could be done with adding an array of user id to a certain `invited_id` column

Comment: ok, so what about an invited column on your list model, set as boolean and then render the list in your view dependent upon if the user_id matches and the invited is true? to invite a user to a list could you 1) use actionmailer to send an email 2) post the user_id with a hidden field somewhere. Sorry if that doesnt make much sense, easier when theres some code in front of you

Comment: Would it not be possible for a user to access all lists if they are only invited to one?

Comment: depends on what logic you use to stop that happening, if thats what you want

Comment: I would like to have function a tiny bit like trello where a board/list is set to private and you can invite members to that board, they can then access and edit items within it. Basecamp uses a similar auth function. Is there any documentation of this kind of process out there?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Membership table which will act as a join table between a User and List. You can then add an :admin attribute to the Membership model with a boolean type.

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :lists, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :list
end
```